# Set my music player as default music player

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-mediaplayer, intentfilter

I'm trying to give the possibility to set my app as default music player, but i found two problems.

**The first one** is about the manifst declaration: According to Google music app Manifest ([manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml)) the code to put on my selected activity is:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="media"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But if I try to open a music file, my application isn't in the list of compatible apps (**why?**). So I tried specyfing the file extension, in this way:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Dashboard"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp3" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This code is working for me, but i think is not the best way.
There is another activity with some important content-filter, and i don't know if it is the problem. It is the first activity (so the launching one, a login activity). his maifest declaration is

```
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In this moment I can set my app as default when a .mp3 file is launched, but here **the second problem**:
I can't intercept the     `Uri` from     `Intent` when the my app is on background. I tried to put     `getIntent().getData()` on     `OnCreate, OnResume and OnStart`, but the Data is always     `null` when the music file is cliked and my app is on background. While it is non null when my app is not in background. **Where/What have I to do to solve?**

Comment: "But it is not working for me" -- please explain what "is not working for me" means. "I can't intercept the Uri from Intent when the my app is on background" -- did you override `onNewIntent()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare With "But is not working for me"  I means that my application isn't in the list of compatible apps when i try to open a music file from a file explorer (I use es file explore). 
And no, i don't override onNewIntent, have i to do?

Comment: "i don't override onNewIntent, have i to do?" -- if you have an activity instance that is being reused, the second and subsequent `Intents` are handed to `onNewIntent()`, not `onCreate()`. "I means that my application isn't in the list of compatible apps when i try to open a music file from a file explorer" -- presumably, your file explorer uses `Uri` values with a `file` scheme, at least on Android 6.0 and older. Android 7.0+ has restrictions on using that scheme.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok now thaks with onNewIntent() I'm able to intercept second sequent Intent.
But I have not solved the second problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now answer to my own question. Thanks to CommonsWare comments and thanks to his old answer to another question:

About the manifest this lines worked good for me, just change my actual intent-filter with:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

About the non intercepted Data when app is on Background, I Solved in this way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*...*/
    interceptExternalIntentAndPlaySongFromUri(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    interceptExternalIntentAndPlaySongFromUri(intent);
}

private boolean interceptExternalIntentAndPlaySongFromUri(Intent intent){
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null && intent.getAction() != null && 
intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)){      
        String scheme = data.getScheme();
        String filename = "";
        if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
            filename = data.getPath();
        } else {
            filename = data.toString();
        }
        player.setDataSource(filename);
        setIntent(new Intent());        //this is to remove the last intent 
//without the above line, last request is reloaded when the user open another app 
//and return in this
        return true;        //has intercepted an external intent
    }
    return false;           //has not intent to intercept
}
```

Thanks still @CommonsWare.